# Title not showing

Tags: titles

I am trying to make a title page for my thesis using LaTeX, but nothing shows up. I have read other questions, but I still don't manage to get it 
correct. What I have done is:

```
      \documentclass[reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.8, .8, 1}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathcomp}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tensor}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\newlength\mytemplen
\newsavebox\mytempbox

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mybluebox{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
       {\@mybluebox}%
       {\@mybluebox[0pt]}}

\def\@mybluebox[#1]{%
    \@ifnextchar[%]
       {\@@mybluebox[#1]}%
       {\@@mybluebox[#1][0pt]}}

\def\@@mybluebox[#1][#2]#3{
    \sbox\mytempbox{#3}%
    \mytemplen\ht\mytempbox
    \advance\mytemplen #1\relax
    \ht\mytempbox\mytemplen
    \mytemplen\dp\mytempbox
    \advance\mytemplen #2\relax
    \dp\mytempbox\mytemplen
    \colorbox{myblue}{\hspace{1em}\usebox{\mytempbox}\hspace{1em}}}
    \makeatother

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\vhtable}{\rule{30pt}{30pt}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\bU}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\bH}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\text{sgn}}
\newcommand{\pw}{p^w}
\newcommand{\epsw}{\varepsilon^w}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ud}{u^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\md}{m^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\nd}{n^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\psid}{\psi_{\delta}}
\newcommand{\cde}{c^{\delta}}
\newcommand*\VF[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{%
    #1%
    \\\hspace{\linewidth}%
    \textbf{Source:} #2%
  }%
}
\newcommand\citecolor[1]{\@namedef{keycolor#1}{\color{black}}}
\newcommand{\mde}{m^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\nde}{n^{\delta}}
\newcommand{\ude}{u^{\delta}}
\newlength\dlf  
\newcommand\alignedbox[2]{

{
\settowidth\dlf{$\displaystyle #1$}  

\addtolength\dlf{\fboxsep+\fboxrule}  

\hspace{-\dlf}  

\boxed{#1 #2}

}
}
\newcommand\MyTabHeadings{% 
\rowcolor{Tab}\rowstyle{\bfseries\color{white}}}
\newcommand{\mT}{\widetilde{m}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\newtheorem{deff}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.\ }{0em}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces
}

\newcolumntype{=}{
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}
}

\newcolumntype{+}{
  >{\@rowstyle}
}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\nl@org@contentsline\contentsline
  \def\contentsline#1{
    \def\nl@current@levelname{#1}
    \nl@org@contentsline{#1}
  }%
}


\protected\def\numberline#1{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\nl@align{%
      nl@align@%
      \@ifundefined{nl@current@levelname}{}{\nl@current@levelname}%
    }%
    \edef\nl@align{%
      \@ifundefined{\nl@align}\nl@align@{\csname\nl@align\endcsname}%
    }%
    \@ifundefined{nl@numberline@\nl@align}{%
      \errmessage{Unknown alignment '\nl@align' for \noexpand\numberline}%
      \nl@numberline@l{#1}%
    }{%
      \csname nl@numberline@\nl@align\endcsname{#1}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}


\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@l}[1]{
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@c}[1]{% 
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 \hfil}%
}
\newcommand*{\nl@numberline@r}[1]{% 
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil#1 }%
}


\def\nl@align@{l}
\def\nl@align@section{r}

\makeatletter    

\makeatother

\makeatletter    


\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\makenomenclature
\makeglossary
\makeatletter

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname r@tocindent0\endcsname{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\title{title name}
\author{My name}
\date{Spring 2017}
\maketitle
\newpage


\begin{abstract}
\normalsize
Abstract
\end{abstract}



 \newpage
    {
      \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
      \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    }

    \makeatletter
    \let\toc@pre\relax
    \let\toc@post\relax
    \makeatother
\section{\textbf{Introduction}}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't show anything in my LaTeX document. I am using `article` document class.

Does anyone know what I should do differently?

Comment: There was a missing `}` for the title ... Please show the minimal document that has this issue, not just fragments

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include the } in the question. I have included it now.

Comment: Yes, but putting that fragment into a minimal document with `article` class I get the title

Comment: `reqno` is no class option for `article`, but that's not the cause of the issue

Comment: If you want an actual **Title page**, you would have to include something like `\clearpage` after the title. Currently you put the title above the following text. This is fine in an article setting, for a thesis/book like setting, take an appropriate document class or use `…\maketitle \clearpage text`

Comment: Or use the titlepage documentclass option.

Comment: @Huang_d: According to the O.P. `nothing shows up`, so this means there is no title at all. I don't think that `\clearpage` is the issue here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: OP mentions "title page" in the question, so I figured part of the question was about making a separate page for the title. The other commentators already mentioned that the code compiles without error for others. David, could you provide the log for your file or an image of what you see when you compile this exact code?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I have included more of the latex-document. There is nothing which shows up (it just starts with the abstract on page 1).

Comment: @David: Oh my god, that preamble is a mess ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below mentioned lines are causing the issue,

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter.\ }{0em}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
```

By commenting these lines, title text comes in output

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}` is the only line responsible for the OP's issue.

Comment: Fantastic, I got the title showing at the first page when I deleted those three lines! Thank you very much!